# is there a way to have midl generate each interface in a separate .h?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, idl, midl

I have a bunch of objects that inherit abstracts interfaces generated from an idl file. Each object that use of theses interfaces include the same file interfaces.h which contain all the c++ generated abstract classes that map to the idl interface.

Each time I change anything into interfaces.idl every classes that depend on this have to be rebuild since interfaces.h change. Is there a flag or something to tell midl to generate each abstract class in its own .h ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to put each interface in its own IDL file, or divide them into multiple IDLs according to rate-of-change.

Then include (or is it #import -- I forget) these interface IDLs into the main library IDL, which will produce the type library, if you need that.

Comment: That's possible but not very easy to do because I integrate typelib inside the application. Adding a separate library for each would be painful.

Midl has everything it needs to split the .h, I expected someone give me the magic flag of the magic tool to do it.

Comment: There should still only need to be one type library -- have one master IDL that includes each interface IDL and contains the library block. Does that not work for you?

Comment: I should have read more carefully, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample on how to organize the idl to generate separate .h files and a single typelib. The correct directive is import.

**main.idl**

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

import "frag1.idl";
import "frag2.idl";

[
    uuid(1BECE2AF-2792-49b9-B133-BBC89C850D6F),
    version(1.0),
    helpstring("Bibliothèque de types")
]
library Library
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    interface IFrag1;
    interface IFrag2;
}
```

**frag1.idl**

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

[
    object,
    uuid(9AEB517B-48B9-4628-8DD3-4A0BA8D39BEF),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    helpstring("Interface IFrag1"),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IFrag1 : IDispatch {
    HRESULT frag1();
};
```

**frag2.idl**

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

[
    object,
    uuid(D60835D4-E1B1-40fb-B583-A75373EF15BE),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    helpstring("Interface IFrag2"),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IFrag2 : IDispatch {
    HRESULT frag2();
};
```